# How I can share google slide Presentation API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-slides-api

I'm using Google slide API in my project, and I want to share a presentation with some gmail account using php code not with Google slide interface.
I see G-Slide API Doc but I didn't found anything about that.

Comment: I imagine it is not supported in the API then.

Comment: Oh!,That not good. There is a risk if I make it public ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Google Drive API to update sharing settings for presentations created using the Slides API. Documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions

The `fileId` in the Drive API is the same as the `presentationId` in Slides.